# Internet Explorer button CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, internet-explorer-8, background-color

I am using a gradient for my button background color, and this only works in non IE browsers. I am trying to set a solid background color for IE. When I place the background style before the background gradients in the stylesheet, it simply doesn't show up. When I place it after, it overrides the gradient in all browsers.

Without it, my button is completely transparent. Can someone help me figure out how to give a background color only to IE? (versions 8 and 9) Or even better.. to set a gradient?

Here is the CSS which works in browsers except IE. The solid background color doesn't show up at all though:

```
button {
        background: #3485bf;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #59a3d4 0%,
        #3485bf);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#59a3d4),
        to(#3485bf));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Filters. Something like

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#59a3d4', endColorstr='#3485bf');
```

should do the job for you.

See [Transitions and Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This link explains how to get gradients working in all modern browsers, and then including fall back background colors if on older browsers:

http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/